# ionic errors with unit testing ionic 4 app

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am trying to write the most basic of unit tests like this one here

```
it('should create the app', async(() => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    const app = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
    expect(app).toBeTruthy();
}));
```

and I always get errors like

> Failed: Template parse errors: Can't bind to 'routerLink' since it
>   isn't a known property of 'ion-item'.
>   1. If 'ion-item' is an Angular component and it has 'routerLink' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
>   2. If 'ion-item' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
>   3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("ggle auto-hide="false"
>   *ngFor="let p of appPages">
>               ][routerLink]="[p.url]">
>                 
>             "): ng:///DynamicTestModule/AppComponent.html@6:49 The pipe 'translate' could not be found ("
>                 
>                     [ERROR ->]             {{ p.title | translate }}
>                 
>                "

it's like ng test unit tests doesn't accept any ionic elements in html? I am importing indeed the forms module and the ionic module in my spec file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of testing, you have to provide the `NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA` property in your TestBed to prevent schema errors, you don't need to provide IonicModule :

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  schemas: [ NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA ]
})
.compileComponents();
```

it looks like you have to provide the TranslateModule.